# search code in servlet to mysql?

Tags: mysql, servlets

what is searching code in servlet to mysql?

I need simple coding anyone pls help me

i created a register page (Name,Qualification,Country,State) using with Html and I created a register table in mysql,

then i created servlet page to get the values from user to db,that values was successfully inserted into mysql table..

then i given a search box in my home page.

now i want to get the table value's using with search option

Ex: using with "name" i want to search value's from mysql..

i need simple searching code in servlet don't paste more coding i am fresher in Software development..

Answer (score 3):

I create a simple demo project which you mention, i use `jstl:core` library which can be download from [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.1/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar)

***web.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID"
        version="3.1">
        <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
        <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>controller.MyController</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/MyController</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

***index.jsp***

```
 <%@ page
        language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@ taglib
        uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        prefix="c"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta
        http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form
        action="MyController"
        method="post">
        <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value="yourUserName"> <input
            type="submit"
            value="Search">
    </form>
        <table title="Users List">
            <c:forEach
                items="${users}"
                var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td>${user.id}</td>
                    <td>${user.name}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***MyController.java***

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import domain.User;

public class MyController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyController() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Get name request parameter
        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        // User user1 = new User();
        // User user2 = new User();
        // user1.setId(0);
        // user1.setName("test1");
        // user2.setId(0);
        // user2.setName("test2");

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        // users.add(user1);
        // users.add(user2);



         //DB Operation query your users
         users=query(name);

        request.setAttribute("users", users);

        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

so `MyController#query` method should be called from your service layer, and query according to your criteria(in demo name or can be anything)

***EDIT:*** Be sure `user` has get property methods, like `getId` and `getName` in this example.

Comment: I think setAttribute() should come after db query() call.

Comment: @RaviThapliyalThanks i update my answer according to your review.