# Java Spring - Redirect page to "outage" based on db cell value.

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jsp, web

I'm looking to setup a "dynamic" outage page for my site, which is based on Spring and sitting on an Oracle 11g db.

In the DB, I have a one cell table, with a flag of "Up" or "Down" that can be manually updated.

so When a user clicks the "action" button, I would like it to check said flag, if value = "up" to go page1, if value = "down" go to page2.

My java is pretty weak however, and surprisingly, Google has been of little help.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Implementing this would be a small project in itself, hence I will not be able to provide complete code. But, I would suggest using **Spring MVC** for handling the button click and handling the page re-directs. Then you can use **Spring JDBC** to query the database to know the outage status.

Comment: Please check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584916/search-code-in-servlet-to-mysql/28587931#28587931 it is similar with your demo project requirements.