# How does jsp show additional data based on processing done by servlet called by jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

User enters a search into an jsp page

/app/index.jsp

and clicks on submit button for that page sends processing to a servlet and changes url when clicked to /app/search?id=1234

The servlet processes a request, if there is only one search result then it redirects to a page for that result, and thats works fine.

But if there are no results I want to redirect back to the /app/index.jsp but I want it to show an error (that was generated by the servlet). Whats the easiest way to do this ?

***Attempted Solution***

So in my Servlet I have:

```
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You didnt enter anything to search for");
            request.setAttribute("error", "You didnt enter anything to search for");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;
        }
```

(note the debugging so I can confirm in my tomcat log that this code is actually being run, which it is)

and then my index.jsp says

```
<h3><%request.getAttribute("error");%></h3>
```

but when the page is displayed it just has

```
<h3></h3>
```

it never has anything in it

**Solution**
I was missing an equals sign , changing to

```
<%=request.getAttribute("error")%>
```

fixed it.

Comment: Put the message into the request and forward to the search page?

Comment: @Dave Newton please expand

Comment: I'm not sure how to expand much on that; set a request attribute with the message, forward (not redirect, the message will be lost) to the search page, and on the search page, if there's a message present, display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the request with error message like;

```
request.setAttribute("errorMsg", "Error:No users find");
RequestDispatcher rd = null;
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

for more detail, you can check my answer which has similar [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584916/search-code-in-servlet-to-mysql/28587931#28587931)

Comment: thanks So I did this request.setAttribute("error","Error Message");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                return; and in my jsp I have <h3><%request.getAttribute("error");%></h3> but a message never gets displayed ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor Please share your code at your question as an edit; so i can check well.

Comment: figured it was missing an '=' in the jsp